# Jquery filter is hiding the div that is inside div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 filters for filering some divs. but when a filter button is pressend the div content is hidden. For a better example i have build a JSFiddle

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8vwbpLtv/17/)

Html is :

```
<!-- Rating  Filter Menu -->
<h4><a href="#rating-filter">Rating</a></h4>
  <div id="rating-filter">
      <div>
         <ul>
           <li data-stars-id="alls"> <a href="#">Toate<small class="total"></small></a> </li>
           <li data-stars-id="3"> <a href="#">3 STARS<small class="total-3"></small></a> </li>
           <li data-stars-id="4"> <a href="#">4 STARS<small class="total-4"></small></a> </li>
           <li data-stars-id="5"> <a href="#">5 STARS<small class="total-1"></small></a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
<!-- Board  Filter Menu -->
<h4><a href="#board-filter">Board Type</a></h4>
  <div id="board-filter">
      <div>
         <ul>
           <li data-board-id="allb"> <a href="#">Toate<small class="total"></small></a> </li>
           <li data-board-id="Half Board"> <a href="#">Half Board<small class="total-hb"></small></a> </li>
           <li data-board-id="Full Board"> <a href="#">Full Board<small class="total-fb"></small></a> </li>
           <li data-board-id="Breakfast"> <a href="#">Breakfast<small class="total-bb"></small></a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
<!-- End Menu -->
<!-- Start Listing -->
<div id="hotel-list" class="hotel-list">
    <div stars="3" board="Full Board"><div>Test for 3 Stars / Full Board</div>3 STARS / FULL BOARD</div>
  <div stars="3" board="Breakfast"><div>Test for 3 Stars / Breakfast</div>3 STARS / BREAKFAST</div>
  <div stars="4" board="Half Board"><div>Test for 4 Stars / Half Board</div>4 STARS / HALF BOARD</div>
  <div stars="5" board="Full Board"><div>Test for 5 Stars / Full Board</div>5 STARS / FULL BOARD</div>
  <div stars="4" board="Half Board"><div>Test for 4 Stars / Half Board</div>4 STARS / HALF BOARD</div>
  <div stars="5" board="Full Board"><div>Test for 5 Stars / Full Board</div>5 STARS / FULL BOARD</div>
</div>
<!-- End Listing -->
```

jQuery is:

```
//Rating
$("#rating-filter li").on("click", function () {
    id = $(this).attr("data-stars-id");
    if (id == "alls") {
        $("div[stars]").show()
    } else {
        $('#hotel-list div').show();
        $('#hotel-list div').filter(function(){
            return $(this).attr('stars') != id
        }).hide();
    }
    return false;
});
//Board
$("#board-filter li").on("click", function () {
    id = $(this).attr("data-board-id");
    if (id == "allb") {
        $("div[board]").show()
    } else {
        $('#hotel-list div').show();
        $('#hotel-list div').filter(function(){
            return $(this).attr('board') != id
        }).hide();
    }
    return false;
});
```

So the code is filering somehow but it hide the content from the other div that is inside it.

Comment: Don't create your own attributes. Use `data-stars="3"` instead of `stars="3"`.

Comment: Can't you change the markup ?

Comment: Hiding a DIV is supposed to hide its content. What do you want to happen instead?

Comment: if you go to the js fiddle an clik an option you will observ that only part of the DIV is shown up instead all.

Comment: Hide and show use "display :none" so the children are also hidden. Either change your filter or opt for "visibilty" which can be overridden for child elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend you to replace these custom attributes with `data` attributes and use classes when selecting hotels/filters elements. It would be much easier to extend and controll in jQuery, using just single `on click` event for both (or as many as you like) filters :

```js
$(".filters li").on("click", function () {
    id = $(this).data("id");
    filter = $(this).data("filter");
    $("#hotel-list .hotels").show() && id == "all" || $('#hotel-list .hotels:not([data-'+filter+'="'+id+'"])').hide();
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Rating  Filter Menu -->
<h4><a href="#rating-filter">Rating</a></h4>
  <div id="rating-filter" class="filters">
      <div>
         <ul>
           <li data-id="all" data-filter="stars"> <a href="#">Toate<small class="total"></small></a> </li>
           <li data-id="3" data-filter="stars"> <a href="#">3 STARS<small class="total-3"></small></a> </li>
           <li data-id="4" data-filter="stars"> <a href="#">4 STARS<small class="total-4"></small></a> </li>
           <li data-id="5" data-filter="stars"> <a href="#">5 STARS<small class="total-1"></small></a></li>
         </ul>
       </div>
    </div>
<!-- Board  Filter Menu -->
<h4><a href="#board-filter">Board Type</a></h4>
  <div id="board-filter"  class="filters">
      <div>
         <ul>
           <li data-id="all" data-filter="board"> <a href="#">Toate<small class="total"></small></a> </li>
           <li data-id="Half Board" data-filter="board"> <a href="#">Half Board<small class="total-hb"></small></a> </li>
           <li data-id="Full Board" data-filter="board"> <a href="#">Full Board<small class="total-fb"></small></a> </li>
           <li data-id="Breakfast" data-filter="board"> <a href="#">Breakfast<small class="total-bb"></small></a></li>
         </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
<!-- End Menu -->
<!-- Start Listing -->
<div id="hotel-list" class="hotel-list">
  <div data-stars="3" data-board="Full Board" class="hotels"><div>Test for 3 Stars / Full Board</div>3 STARS / FULL BOARD</div>
  <div data-stars="3" data-board="Breakfast" class="hotels"><div>Test for 3 Stars / Breakfast</div>3 STARS / BREAKFAST</div>
  <div data-stars="4" data-board="Half Board" class="hotels"><div>Test for 4 Stars / Half Board</div>4 STARS / HALF BOARD</div>
  <div data-stars="5" data-board="Full Board" class="hotels"><div>Test for 5 Stars / Full Board</div>5 STARS / FULL BOARD</div>
  <div data-stars="4" data-board="Half Board" class="hotels"><div>Test for 4 Stars / Half Board</div>4 STARS / HALF BOARD</div>
  <div data-stars="5" data-board="Full Board" class="hotels"><div>Test for 5 Stars / Full Board</div>5 STARS / FULL BOARD</div>
</div>
<!-- End Listing -->
```

Comment: How can i cumulate multiple board type on a single button filter. Ex: i have divs with Bed And Breakfast and some of them with Breakfast Buffet, can i use the Breakfast button to show both of them ?

Comment: @CARASS , it could be done as long as the filter values are single words. F.ex.:  this: `Half Board` will be this: `HalfBoard`. Can you change them to single words?

Comment: its a dymanic data that comes from an API Webservice. No other solution ?

Comment: Well... It will require a bit more processing, but yes, it's still possible. This however needs  a *comma* sign (or similar) in data-board attribute (to separate values), like this: `data-board="Full Board, Breakfast"`. Is it ok?

Comment: @CARASS , take a look at this : http://jsfiddle.net/84fkw5fu/ . You can use *comma* (`,`) separator in filters, like: `<li data-id="Breakfast, Half Board" ...` (click on the last item of "Board Type" filters)

Comment: it needed a split :) sometimes the solution is in our eyes but we huve dust :) Thanks mate :)

Answer (score 0):

Change your selector to `$("#hotel-list > div"). This just matches the DIVs that are immediate children of`#hotel-list`, so you don't hide the grandchildren.

```
//Rating
$("#rating-filter li").on("click", function () {
    id = $(this).attr("data-stars-id");
    if (id == "alls") {
        $("div[stars]").show()
    } else {
        $('#hotel-list > div').show();
        $('#hotel-list > div').filter(function(){
            return $(this).attr('stars') != id
        }).hide();
    }
    return false;
});
//Board
$("#board-filter li").on("click", function () {
    id = $(this).attr("data-board-id");
    if (id == "allb") {
        $("div[board]").show()
    } else {
        $('#hotel-list > div').show();
        $('#hotel-list > div').filter(function(){
            return $(this).attr('board') != id
        }).hide();
    }
    return false;
});
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/8vwbpLtv/18/)